# How to find pull requests by you on Bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket

I can't figure out how to find pull requests made by me on Bitbucket.

Comment: What does this say? https://bitbucket.org/dashboard/pullrequests?section=created

Comment: Wow that worked! Is there a way to navigate to that from the UI? (don't want to have to remember the URL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the dashboard of being signed in, there will be sub-menus of:

- Overview
- Pull requests
- Issues
- Snippets

Click on the "Pull requests" navigation menu item and then click on the "Mine" that appears on that page.

You'll see something like the following:

[image: pull requests on bitbucket]

That page will list all of [the pull requests you've created on Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/dashboard/pullrequests?section=created).

If you can't see that as an option, you may need to [turn that option on under your account settings](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/12209/pull-request-list-20-feedback).

Comment: Weird, I don't see those tabs in my bitbucket. I see this: http://imgur.com/AvO4FEL

Comment: Are you a project owner? Or maybe try: https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/12209/pull-request-list-20-feedback

Comment: The solution from your link works! Thanks!